# Server fails when downloading large files with PHP

Tags: php, download, sftp, large-files, phpseclib

I'm using the SFTP functions of [PHPSecLib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to download files from an FTP server.

The line

```
$sftp->get($fname);
```

works if the file is up to 200MB, but if it's 300MB, the browser responds with "Firefox can't find the file at [download.php]". That is, it says it can't find the php file I use for downloading the remote file.

At first I thought this was due to the `memory_limit` setting in php.ini, but it doesn't matter if it's set to 128M or 350M; 200MB files still work, and 300MB files fail. And it fails after ten seconds, so `max_execution_time` or `max_input_time` don't seem to be the culprits. What could be wrong?

Comment: What's it say in the error log on the server? Is the server windows, linux?

Comment: What of the `max_upload_size`?

Comment: upload_max_filesize is set to 500M. ("max_upload_size" doesn't exist). It's a Linux server - I'm sending an email to ask about the error logs.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);`?

Comment: set_time_limit shouldn't make any difference unless the script exceeds the max_execution_time, which is 30 seconds. (Edit: Tried it anyway, didn't work.)

Comment: Found the error logs! It says "`Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 237502465 bytes) in [path]/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 1536`". Can I affect the allowed memory in some other way than by using memory_limit?

Comment: Try defining simple logs

`define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_SIMPLE);`

Answer (score 2):

Something else you could do...

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
$sftp->login('username', 'password');

$start = 0;
while (true) {
    $response = $sftp->get('1mb', false, $start, 1024);
    $start+= 1024;
    if (empty($response)) {
        break;
    }
    echo $response;
}
```

ie. download the file in multiple chunks.

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly recommend that you put in your code `set_time_limit(0);` at the very very top of your php file (even before any includes) since you're dealing with operations you don't know how much time they will take.

I'd say this is a case of the webserver/browser timing out on not sending/receiving any data over a "long" period of time. To fix this we have to alter a bit the SFTP.php file, namely the Net_SFTP class, then go to the get method (line 1482 if you have phpseclib 0.3.1) and add some stuff inside the only "while" control structure you have there (I'll paste the entire function below), to add the following code:

```
if (strtolower(PHP_SAPI) != 'cli') { // run this if request is handled by a webserver (like your case)
    $my_iter++;

    if($my_iter > 1024){
        $my_iter = 0; // reset the counter
        echo "transferring ... " . date("G:i:s") . "<br />"; // send something to the buffer
    }

    // flush the buffers and prevent the timeout by actually outputting something to the browser
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start();
    usleep(100); // just in case, try removing this delay
}
```

Which basically outputs something from time to time (1024 iterations of this while) and flush the buffers to actually output something to the browser. Feel free to adjust the values.
This is code (SFTP class) not meant to be ran from a webserver because of these problems. I mean, you CAN, but you'll run into some issues, like this one.

Also, if you try to send() you'll have to do a similar modification on the corresponding method, but hopefully this will cover your problem (at least this fixed my timeouts problems here on my local dev box).

Now, the full method modification goes below, as promised ;-)

```
function get($remote_file, $local_file = false)
{
    if (!($this->bitmap & NET_SSH2_MASK_LOGIN)) {
        return false;
    }

    $remote_file = $this->_realpath($remote_file);
    if ($remote_file === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $packet = pack('Na*N2', strlen($remote_file), $remote_file, NET_SFTP_OPEN_READ, 0);
    if (!$this->_send_sftp_packet(NET_SFTP_OPEN, $packet)) {
        return false;
    }

    $response = $this->_get_sftp_packet();
    switch ($this->packet_type) {
        case NET_SFTP_HANDLE:
            $handle = substr($response, 4);
            break;
        case NET_SFTP_STATUS: // presumably SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE or SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED
            $this->_logError($response);
            return false;
        default:
            user_error('Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
    }

    if ($local_file !== false) {
        $fp = fopen($local_file, 'wb');
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $content = '';
    }

    $read = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (strtolower(PHP_SAPI) != 'cli') { // run this if request is handled by a webserver (like your case)
            $my_iter++;

            if($my_iter > 1024){
                $my_iter = 0; // reset the counter
                echo "transferring ... " . date("G:i:s") . "<br />"; // send something to the buffer
            }

            // flush the buffers and prevent the timeout by actually outputting something to the browser
            ob_end_flush();
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            ob_start();
            usleep(100); // just in case, try removing this delay
        }

        $packet = pack('Na*N3', strlen($handle), $handle, 0, $read, 1 << 20);
        if (!$this->_send_sftp_packet(NET_SFTP_READ, $packet)) {
            if ($local_file !== false) {
                fclose($fp);
            }
            return false;
        }

        $response = $this->_get_sftp_packet();
        switch ($this->packet_type) {
            case NET_SFTP_DATA:
                $temp = substr($response, 4);
                $read+= strlen($temp);
                if ($local_file === false) {
                    $content.= $temp;
                } else {
                    fputs($fp, $temp);
                }
                break;
            case NET_SFTP_STATUS:
                $this->_logError($response);
                break 2;
            default:
                user_error('Expected SSH_FXP_DATA or SSH_FXP_STATUS', E_USER_NOTICE);
                if ($local_file !== false) {
                    fclose($fp);
                }
                return false;
        }
    }

    if ($local_file !== false) {
        fclose($fp);
    }

    if (!$this->_send_sftp_packet(NET_SFTP_CLOSE, pack('Na*', strlen($handle), $handle))) {
        return false;
    }

    $response = $this->_get_sftp_packet();
    if ($this->packet_type != NET_SFTP_STATUS) {
        user_error('Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS', E_USER_NOTICE);
        return false;
    }

    $this->_logError($response);

    // check the status from the NET_SFTP_STATUS case in the above switch after the file has been closed
    if ($status != NET_SFTP_STATUS_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($content)) {
        return $content;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed by the answer, but at the moment I think it was a memory-related problem. As I wrote in the comments above, I found `"Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted"` in the error logs, and after the hosting provider increased `memory_limit` to 512M, the 300MB file could be downloaded. It seems that the php.ini file that they provided earlier - in which I had tried setting `memory_limit` to a high value - didn't actually change the memory limit, even though the values from that file showed up when I checked with `phpinfo()` (!?).

Comment: Try downloading a 2 GB (or even bigger) file to see if you don't hit any webserver timeouts, I too was able to download a 300 MB file, but just for the sake of it I tried with bigger files to see if it was behaving fine and hit the bug I showed on the answer. Also was hit by memory problems, switched to 256M on php.ini and then back to 128M which was what I had before and "magically" never had those back (that was weird).